# Parallel Battery Packs-Any concerns or considerations besides diodes for used non-rechargeable AA?

Tags: batteries, dc

A project I am working which involves an Arduino controlling RGB LED strips.  To avoid overloading the Arduino, I plan to use a 5v 3A supply for 2 strips near each other (they want 1A each) but for the two distant¹ LED strips I will need to power them with 4xAA in a pack.  For reliability I am thinking of using two packs in parallel.  If my understanding is correct, using a diode on the 5v² line of each pack will prevent possible back flow into the packs.  Are there any considerations besides a diode I need to consider?  Can I just use regular diodes as opposed to Shokey diodes like I see in a few of the other questions related to this topic?  The batteries will partially used and guaranteed to be at different usage.  Included is a circuit diagram example.
[image: Arduino and 4 "LED Strips"]
With this example instead of showing 2 single voltage sources I am using 2 "AC" sources offset to simulate 2 battery packs with each at a different voltage.

¹ Using RJ45 connectors and cables, the distant strips will have received the signal of RGB+Ground on each pair and a battery pack where the RJ45 break out to diodes and the LED strip.

² I know that usually I would be looking 6v but I am using batteries that were used in microphone transmitter packs we used at the community theater.  These batteries usually have 50-75% charge so they still work for LED powering for shows, but we never do more than 2 shows on a battery pack.

Comment: That would work. The battery would last longer with a Schottky diode, or at least the LEDs would be brighter at a given battery voltage, since you waste less voltage drop that with a "normal" diode.